# Why do I receive "Http failure response for http://localhost:3000/areas: 0 Unknown Error" when I turn off my database instead of a 404?

Tags: angular, http, cors

I have a mongodb server running at port 3000, to which I can usually connect without any issue. In order to test my error handling and message display in the UI, I've deliberately turned it off to receive a connection error.

```
private modifyAndRethrow(): (response: HttpErrorResponse) => ObservableInput<any> {
  return (response: HttpErrorResponse) => {
    throw response.error?.code as string || `${response.status}`;
  };
}

public read(dataType: DataType, id: string): Observable<DataEntry | undefined> {
  return this._http.get<DataEntry>(`${IDbFacade.BASEURL}/${dataType}/${id}`, { observe: 'response' })
                  .pipe(map((response: HttpResponse<DataEntry>) => response.body || undefined),
                        first(),
                        catchError(this.modifyAndRethrow()));
}
```

I was very surprised to see "Unknown Error" displayed and checking the response.status in my modifyAndRethrow method, it was 0 instead of a 404, as I had expected.

I didn't even know an HTTP status code of 0 existed, and from what I've read, it is generally a CORS issue. I do have CORS properly set up, so I don't receive any CORS errors when my server is running. Chrome also usually tells me if there's a CORS error, instead of "Unknown".

```
const cors = require('cors');
var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:4200'
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));
```

When I change the port in the request URL to 4200 (i.e. the one of my application) I do receive a 404 as expected. How does CORS take precedence over a non-existing target URL? How can I filter out a 404 error from this as that is what it actually is?

Comment: 0 doesn't seem to be a valid response... but it's not surprising since you shut down the server, no?  (The server's not there to respond with any kind of error.)

Comment: @browsermator 404 is a client error though. No need for a server response I'd assume. Shouldn't the client interpret the lack of a target as 404?

Comment: http error codes come from the server in the response header.

Comment: CORS errors will show in browser's console.... those are created by the client/browser, though I'm not sure what happens if the server is down.... you'll probably get "CORS request did not succeed" if it's trying a cross-site, non-simple request.